# How to make FeatureUnion return Dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline, feature-extraction

So I currently have a Pipeline that has a lot of customer transformers:

```
p = Pipeline([
("GetTimeFromDate",TimeTransformer("Date")), #Custom Transformer that adds ["time"] column
("GetZipFromAddress",ZipTransformer("Address")), #Custom Transformer that adds ["zip"] column
("GroupByTimeandZip",GroupByTransformer(["time","zip"]) #Custom Transformer that adds onehot columns
])
```

Each transformer takes in a pandas dataframe and returns the same dataframe with one or more new columns.  It actually works quite well, but how can I run the "GetTimeFromDate" and the "GetZipFromAddress" steps in parallel?

I would like to use FeatureUnion:

```
f = FeatureUnion([  
("GetTimeFromDate",TimeTransformer("Date")), #Custom Transformer that adds ["time"] column
("GetZipFromAddress",ZipTransformer("Address")), #Custom Transformer that adds ["zip"] column])
])

p = Pipeline([
("FeatureUnionStep",f),
("GroupByTimeandZip",GroupByTransformer(["time","zip"]) #Custom Transformer that adds onehot columns
])
```

But the problem is that FeatureUnion returns a numpy.ndarray, but the "GroupByTimeandZip" step needs a dataframe.

Is there a way I can get FeatureUnion to return a pandas dataframe?

Comment: Hello, to use FeatureUnion with heterogeneous Data sources see : http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/hetero_feature_union.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a `FeatureUnion` to output a `DataFrame` you can use the `PandasFeatureUnion` from this [blog post](https://zablo.net/blog/post/pandas-dataframe-in-scikit-learn-feature-union). Also see the [gist](https://github.com/marrrcin/pandas-feature-union/blob/master/pandas_feature_union.py).